# Multiple Database in a postgres cluster on Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

Is it possible to have multiple databse in a cluster with Crunchydata (postgres)?
When I create a cluster with "pgo create cluster" command I can specify only one database.

```
 -d, --database string                       If specified, sets the name of the initial database that is created for the user. Defaults to the value set in the PostgreSQL Operator configuration, or if that is not present, the name of the cluster
```

But I need multiple database per cluster, and I can't find any official way to create them.

Another question: How can I find the "superuser" username and password to login to PGOAmin Web?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Super credentials are usually generated by the operators on creating the clusters. You can try to see what ConfigMaps and Secrets are added to Kubernetes after creating the cluster. You will find credentials in one of these. PS, I haven't used cruchydata's operator. I have used the one by Zalando.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried all secrets in the cluster namespace and in the operator namespace as well, but none of them worked.

Comment: https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/3.5.2/cli/pgo_user/ Found this. Looks like something that can solve your issue

Comment: Did you find answer to create multiple databases?  Me too looking for the answer

Comment: Same question here: How do we "officially" add databases to the cluster? We could use psql, but would db created in psql get backed up by the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful, however it stated:

> "It may make more sense to have each of your databases in its own
> cluster if you want to have them spread out over your Kubernetes
> topology."

https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/issues/2655

Comment: Liked (good link) but would say that the comment is a bit misleading as it start with "As to "is it recommended," it's up to how you want to organize your data and what your availability and performance requirements are."